# How to update primary key, what have foreign keys pointing to, without "ON UPDATE CASCADE"

Tags: django, postgresql, foreign-keys

I have PostgreSQL database created with Django with lots of tables. Also there are multiple foreign keys between tables.
I need to change `id` (primary key) field of users_user table, but there are a lot of tables that are pointing to it.

Of course ideal solution is to add "ON UPDATE CASCADE" to all of the foreign keys. But in my case its impossible during long sequence of reconciliations, making agreements with other teams about such database model changes.

So, I need a way of changing primary key and all the foreign keys automatically without manually specifying other tables, because there are a lot of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Parts:**

There are a way to update primary and foreign key in a single query without intemediate records, it's described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34383663/2622523

Also, there are a way to know, which tables and columns are linked to my table by foreign keys:

```sql
    SELECT
            tc.table_name, kcu.column_name      
    FROM 
        information_schema.table_constraints AS tc 
        JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu
          ON tc.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name
          AND tc.table_schema = kcu.table_schema
        JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage AS ccu
          ON ccu.constraint_name = tc.constraint_name
          AND ccu.table_schema = tc.table_schema
    WHERE tc.constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY' 
          and (tc.table_name='users_user' or ccu.table_name = 'users_user')
```

And so this two blocks could be combined to generate UPDATE query of a dream.

**Solution:**

This is a query which I've came to:

```sql
with 
-- Source parameters
src as (
    select 
    -- Replace this with your old value, that should be changed
    '7f897d30-8261-11eb-8dcd-0242ac130003' as old_value,
    -- Replace this with your new value, that you need to sed
    'f243cc42-1260-4bf0-a452-8ac94b2382df' as new_value,
    -- Table name, which have to be used
    'users_user' as table_name,
    -- Column that need to be changed
    'id' as field_name
),
-- here we are memorizing foreign keys, pointing to our table
forkeys as (
    SELECT
            tc.table_name, kcu.column_name      
    FROM 
        information_schema.table_constraints AS tc 
        JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu
          ON tc.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name
          AND tc.table_schema = kcu.table_schema
        JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage AS ccu
          ON ccu.constraint_name = tc.constraint_name
          AND ccu.table_schema = tc.table_schema
    WHERE tc.constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY' and 
          (
              tc.table_name=(select table_name from src) 
          or 
              ccu.table_name = (select table_name from src))
          ), 
-- constcructing 'with' part of query
withs as (
    select e'WITH ' || string_agg(q, e',') as w from (
        SELECT
            e'\nupdate_' || table_name || '_' || column_name || e' as (\n    UPDATE "' || table_name 
            || e'" SET "' || column_name || e'" = ''' || (select new_value from src) || ''' where "' 
            || column_name || e'" = ''' || (select old_value from src) || e''' returning "' 
            || column_name || e'"\n)' as q
        FROM 
            forkeys
    ) as i
), 
-- constucting 'main' update part of query
main as (
    select 'UPDATE "' || (select table_name from src) || '" SET "' || (select field_name from src) || '" = ''' 
        || (select new_value from src) || ''' WHERE "' || (select field_name from src) || '" = ''' || (select old_value from src) || ''''  as e

)
-- outputting
select w || e'\n' || e from main, withs
```

**And the output of this script in my case is:**

```sql
WITH 
update_avatar_useravatar_approver_id as (
    UPDATE "avatar_useravatar" SET "approver_id" = 'f243cc42-1260-4bf0-a452-8ac94b2382df' where "approver_id" = '7f897d30-8261-11eb-8dcd-0242ac130003' returning "approver_id"
),
update_avatar_useravatar_user_id as (
    UPDATE "avatar_useravatar" SET "user_id" = 'f243cc42-1260-4bf0-a452-8ac94b2382df' where "user_id" = '7f897d30-8261-11eb-8dcd-0242ac130003' returning "user_id"
),
update_awards_useraward_user_id as (
    UPDATE "awards_useraward" SET "user_id" = 'f243cc42-1260-4bf0-a452-8ac94b2382df' where "user_id" = '7f897d30-8261-11eb-8dcd-0242ac130003' returning "user_id"
),
update_colleagues_colleagues_user_from_id as (
    UPDATE "colleagues_colleagues" SET "user_from_id" = 'f243cc42-1260-4bf0-a452-8ac94b2382df' where "user_from_id" = '7f897d30-8261-11eb-8dcd-0242ac130003' returning "user_from_id"
),
update_colleagues_colleagues_user_to_id as (
    UPDATE "colleagues_colleagues" SET "user_to_id" = 'f243cc42-1260-4bf0-a452-8ac94b2382df' where "user_to_id" = '7f897d30-8261-11eb-8dcd-0242ac130003' returning "user_to_id"
),
update_congratulations_congratulation_from_user_id as (
    UPDATE "congratulations_congratulation" SET "from_user_id" = 'f243cc42-1260-4bf0-a452-8ac94b2382df' where "from_user_id" = '7f897d30-8261-11eb-8dcd-0242ac130003' returning "from_user_id"
),
update_congratulations_congratulation_to_user_id as (
    UPDATE "congratulations_congratulation" SET "to_user_id" = 'f243cc42-1260-4bf0-a452-8ac94b2382df' where "to_user_id" = '7f897d30-8261-11eb-8dcd-0242ac130003' returning "to_user_id"
),
update_django_admin_log_user_id as (
    UPDATE "django_admin_log" SET "user_id" = 'f243cc42-1260-4bf0-a452-8ac94b2382df' where "user_id" = '7f897d30-8261-11eb-8dcd-0242ac130003' returning "user_id"
),
update_following_userfollowing_from_user_id as (
    UPDATE "following_userfollowing" SET "from_user_id" = 'f243cc42-1260-4bf0-a452-8ac94b2382df' where "from_user_id" = '7f897d30-8261-11eb-8dcd-0242ac130003' returning "from_user_id"
),
update_following_userfollowing_to_user_id as (
    UPDATE "following_userfollowing" SET "to_user_id" = 'f243cc42-1260-4bf0-a452-8ac94b2382df' where "to_user_id" = '7f897d30-8261-11eb-8dcd-0242ac130003' returning "to_user_id"
),
update_keycloak_userprofilekeycloak_user_id as (
    UPDATE "keycloak_userprofilekeycloak" SET "user_id" = 'f243cc42-1260-4bf0-a452-8ac94b2382df' where "user_id" = '7f897d30-8261-11eb-8dcd-0242ac130003' returning "user_id"
),
update_location_table_created_by_id as (
    UPDATE "location_table" SET "created_by_id" = 'f243cc42-1260-4bf0-a452-8ac94b2382df' where "created_by_id" = '7f897d30-8261-11eb-8dcd-0242ac130003' returning "created_by_id"
),
update_profile_media_profileimage_author_id as (
    UPDATE "profile_media_profileimage" SET "author_id" = 'f243cc42-1260-4bf0-a452-8ac94b2382df' where "author_id" = '7f897d30-8261-11eb-8dcd-0242ac130003' returning "author_id"
),
update_skills_skillapproved_user_from_id as (
    UPDATE "skills_skillapproved" SET "user_from_id" = 'f243cc42-1260-4bf0-a452-8ac94b2382df' where "user_from_id" = '7f897d30-8261-11eb-8dcd-0242ac130003' returning "user_from_id"
),
update_skills_skillsowners_created_by_id as (
    UPDATE "skills_skillsowners" SET "created_by_id" = 'f243cc42-1260-4bf0-a452-8ac94b2382df' where "created_by_id" = '7f897d30-8261-11eb-8dcd-0242ac130003' returning "created_by_id"
),
update_skills_skillsowners_owner_id as (
    UPDATE "skills_skillsowners" SET "owner_id" = 'f243cc42-1260-4bf0-a452-8ac94b2382df' where "owner_id" = '7f897d30-8261-11eb-8dcd-0242ac130003' returning "owner_id"
),
update_skills_usercompetence_user_id as (
    UPDATE "skills_usercompetence" SET "user_id" = 'f243cc42-1260-4bf0-a452-8ac94b2382df' where "user_id" = '7f897d30-8261-11eb-8dcd-0242ac130003' returning "user_id"
),
update_structure_unit_boss_id as (
    UPDATE "structure_unit" SET "boss_id" = 'f243cc42-1260-4bf0-a452-8ac94b2382df' where "boss_id" = '7f897d30-8261-11eb-8dcd-0242ac130003' returning "boss_id"
),
update_structure_unit_user_id as (
    UPDATE "structure_unit" SET "user_id" = 'f243cc42-1260-4bf0-a452-8ac94b2382df' where "user_id" = '7f897d30-8261-11eb-8dcd-0242ac130003' returning "user_id"
),
update_thanks_thanks_from_user_id as (
    UPDATE "thanks_thanks" SET "from_user_id" = 'f243cc42-1260-4bf0-a452-8ac94b2382df' where "from_user_id" = '7f897d30-8261-11eb-8dcd-0242ac130003' returning "from_user_id"
),
update_thanks_thanks_to_user_id as (
    UPDATE "thanks_thanks" SET "to_user_id" = 'f243cc42-1260-4bf0-a452-8ac94b2382df' where "to_user_id" = '7f897d30-8261-11eb-8dcd-0242ac130003' returning "to_user_id"
),
update_user_profile_userprofile_call_if_absent_user_id as (
    UPDATE "user_profile_userprofile_call_if_absent" SET "user_id" = 'f243cc42-1260-4bf0-a452-8ac94b2382df' where "user_id" = '7f897d30-8261-11eb-8dcd-0242ac130003' returning "user_id"
),
update_user_profile_userprofile_mentor_id as (
    UPDATE "user_profile_userprofile" SET "mentor_id" = 'f243cc42-1260-4bf0-a452-8ac94b2382df' where "mentor_id" = '7f897d30-8261-11eb-8dcd-0242ac130003' returning "mentor_id"
),
update_user_profile_userprofile_recruiter_id as (
    UPDATE "user_profile_userprofile" SET "recruiter_id" = 'f243cc42-1260-4bf0-a452-8ac94b2382df' where "recruiter_id" = '7f897d30-8261-11eb-8dcd-0242ac130003' returning "recruiter_id"
),
update_user_profile_userprofile_user_id as (
    UPDATE "user_profile_userprofile" SET "user_id" = 'f243cc42-1260-4bf0-a452-8ac94b2382df' where "user_id" = '7f897d30-8261-11eb-8dcd-0242ac130003' returning "user_id"
),
update_users_absence_user_id as (
    UPDATE "users_absence" SET "user_id" = 'f243cc42-1260-4bf0-a452-8ac94b2382df' where "user_id" = '7f897d30-8261-11eb-8dcd-0242ac130003' returning "user_id"
),
update_users_car_user_id as (
    UPDATE "users_car" SET "user_id" = 'f243cc42-1260-4bf0-a452-8ac94b2382df' where "user_id" = '7f897d30-8261-11eb-8dcd-0242ac130003' returning "user_id"
),
update_users_device_user_id as (
    UPDATE "users_device" SET "user_id" = 'f243cc42-1260-4bf0-a452-8ac94b2382df' where "user_id" = '7f897d30-8261-11eb-8dcd-0242ac130003' returning "user_id"
),
update_users_education_user_id as (
    UPDATE "users_education" SET "user_id" = 'f243cc42-1260-4bf0-a452-8ac94b2382df' where "user_id" = '7f897d30-8261-11eb-8dcd-0242ac130003' returning "user_id"
),
update_users_knowlanguage_user_id as (
    UPDATE "users_knowlanguage" SET "user_id" = 'f243cc42-1260-4bf0-a452-8ac94b2382df' where "user_id" = '7f897d30-8261-11eb-8dcd-0242ac130003' returning "user_id"
),
update_users_user_functional_manager_id as (
    UPDATE "users_user" SET "functional_manager_id" = 'f243cc42-1260-4bf0-a452-8ac94b2382df' where "functional_manager_id" = '7f897d30-8261-11eb-8dcd-0242ac130003' returning "functional_manager_id"
),
update_users_user_groups_user_id as (
    UPDATE "users_user_groups" SET "user_id" = 'f243cc42-1260-4bf0-a452-8ac94b2382df' where "user_id" = '7f897d30-8261-11eb-8dcd-0242ac130003' returning "user_id"
),
update_users_user_line_manager_id as (
    UPDATE "users_user" SET "line_manager_id" = 'f243cc42-1260-4bf0-a452-8ac94b2382df' where "line_manager_id" = '7f897d30-8261-11eb-8dcd-0242ac130003' returning "line_manager_id"
),
update_users_user_r_functional_manager_id as (
    UPDATE "users_user" SET "r_functional_manager_id" = 'f243cc42-1260-4bf0-a452-8ac94b2382df' where "r_functional_manager_id" = '7f897d30-8261-11eb-8dcd-0242ac130003' returning "r_functional_manager_id"
),
update_users_user_r_line_manager_id as (
    UPDATE "users_user" SET "r_line_manager_id" = 'f243cc42-1260-4bf0-a452-8ac94b2382df' where "r_line_manager_id" = '7f897d30-8261-11eb-8dcd-0242ac130003' returning "r_line_manager_id"
),
update_users_user_user_permissions_user_id as (
    UPDATE "users_user_user_permissions" SET "user_id" = 'f243cc42-1260-4bf0-a452-8ac94b2382df' where "user_id" = '7f897d30-8261-11eb-8dcd-0242ac130003' returning "user_id"
),
update_users_usersvisibilitysettingsmodel_user_id as (
    UPDATE "users_usersvisibilitysettingsmodel" SET "user_id" = 'f243cc42-1260-4bf0-a452-8ac94b2382df' where "user_id" = '7f897d30-8261-11eb-8dcd-0242ac130003' returning "user_id"
),
update_location_userplace_user_id as (
    UPDATE "location_userplace" SET "user_id" = 'f243cc42-1260-4bf0-a452-8ac94b2382df' where "user_id" = '7f897d30-8261-11eb-8dcd-0242ac130003' returning "user_id"
),
update_user_extension_userextension_user_id as (
    UPDATE "user_extension_userextension" SET "user_id" = 'f243cc42-1260-4bf0-a452-8ac94b2382df' where "user_id" = '7f897d30-8261-11eb-8dcd-0242ac130003' returning "user_id"
)
UPDATE "users_user" SET "id" = 'f243cc42-1260-4bf0-a452-8ac94b2382df' WHERE "id" = '7f897d30-8261-11eb-8dcd-0242ac130003'
```

It could be executed and the change would be applied.

**TODOs:**

- Composite primary/foreign keys are not supported yet
- Can cause some troubles if your key is not UUID, didn't tested it.
- The code is "write only" need some refactoring
- Maybe wrap the code into a Pl/PgSQL code block so it could be executed in one pass.